# Ownership of the .config folder in home directory

Tags: macos, command-line, homebrew, permission, git

Who is supposed to be the owner of the `.config` directory under user's home folder?

On my machine it appears to be owned by the `system` user and it is only readable by that user.

Several programs, like **Homebrew** and **git** (which should be allowed to be used **without** root permissions) complain by producing warnings as shown below:

`warning: unable to access '/Users/andrea/.config/git/attributes': Permission denied`

Perhaps the ownership of my `.config` folder was changed in mistake? Who should be the owner?

And if `system` should be the owner, is it safe to make it readable and writable by other users?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `.config` folder is supposed to be owned by the user. It appears that the ownership got changed to **system** by mistake on your machine.

To restore the default permission, execute the following command:

`$ sudo chown -R <username> .config`

When prompted for a password, enter your login password.

Substitute `<username>` with your username. To determine your username, execute the following command and observe the output.

`$ whoami`

Finally, to answer your queries:

> Who is supposed to be the owner of the .config directory under user's home folder?

The logged in user is supposed to be the owner of the `.config` directory.

> And if system should be the owner, is it safe to make it readable and writable by other users?

It is not recommended to do that, unless you have some specific reason to do so.

Comment: I would have just one question: do you know any official source, or well-known reliable source, which states that `config` should be owned by the current user instead of `system`? If yes, could you post a link to it?

Comment: When I say this I mean also that it may not say it explicitly but it is easy to deduce this (for example, "all the standard subfolders of the home folder should be owned by the user")

Comment: There's no official document that I can think of, but the fact is a common knowledge. Perhaps [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7446956) discussion from the Apple Support Community could provide an idea @AndreaCalliaD'Iddio

Comment: Many thanks for the link, and just for a further confirmation that your answer should be right, I have also found [link] (https://askubuntu.com/questions/852265/should-i-change-config-folder-ownership-that-is-in-my-own-home-directory-why-i) question [/link] on AskUbuntu in which they still talk about this `.config` folder (but in a different OS) and they say that in Ubuntu it is also supposed to be owned by the user, so I don't see why MacOS should be different from this point of view... so unless someone disagrees and brings other sources, I will consider yours as the right answer...

Comment: A simpler reason of who the owner should be is that all things under your home directory are owned by you.